# Help regarding Geometry Optimization of a bimetallic surface

Tags: density-functional-theory, geometry-optimization, atomic-simulation-environment, surfaces, cp2k

I am trying to perform a geometry optimization (GEO_OPT) of a FCC 111 $Pt_{0.5}Au_{0.5}$ bimetallic surface (10x10x3) generated from ASE, with a lattice parameter of 3.9 $\overset{\circ}{\mathrm{A}}$ in CP2K. However, after the geometry optimization is completed, the visualization of the coordinates show that the top layer gold atoms are moving away from the surface layer.

I am using `CUTOFF 400` and `REL_CUTOFF 60` for the calculations. I am unable to figure out how to resolve the problem. I think the forces are very high. I am trying a cell optimization calculation.

Will this be useful? Or should I change something else in the geometry optimization calculations?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: As per the request of @Phil Hasnip, I am uploading the images of

1. before optimization[image]
2. After Optimization

[image: After Optimization]

The `MAX_FORCE` is set to 4.5d-4 and `RMS_FORCE` is set to 3d-4 for the optimization. All these values converges as per the cp2k output file. Thanks.

Comment: This is difficult to answer just from your description. Are the forces close to zero, once the optimisation is completed? How far are the top atoms from the next layer? Could you attach some images of the geometry before and after geometry optimisation?

Comment: Thank you @Phil Hasnip for your response. I am uploading the images and the description in the next comment

Comment: @Phil Hasnip I have updated the question. Kindly check

Comment: Are you optimizing the entire cell with all cell-parameters allowed to change, or are you doing a constrained optimization where you are keeping the z-direction fixed?

Comment: @HemanthHaridas I am trying to perform a geometry optimization only keeping the z direction fixed. I am not performing a cell optimization

Comment: What is your cell length in z?

Comment: @HemanthHaridas the cell length is around 30 angstrom, considering the vacuum as well.

Comment: Ok. So what is happening is that you most probably have unbalanced forces on your top layer which would explain the buckling of the surface.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas I understand, but the forces are converging as per the convergence criteria set in the input file. This is causing confusion for me

Comment: Please use a chatroom if you need to discuss further (but please don't create a new one, just use an existing one).